# Eclipse does not build project, or gets too much time to build

Tags: android, eclipse, ant, build

I've been using Eclipse for about 10 months, primarily for Android applications. until last 2 weeks I was very happy with coding, it was very fast to build the code and show me the errors in real time. Now even in small projects it seems to not build anything unless I click "build project option" (build automatically option is on). I don't know it's about Eclipse or ant builder, it turned into a real trouble, any help will be appreciated

Comment: if you have many projects in your workspace, then i guess it may affect. Just create a new workspace and see if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove unused tools in eclipse, increase the VM values like 
-vmargs
-Xms1024m
-Xmx1024m
Close unused projects, try to change workspace location.

Answer (score 1):

You could always try the brute force approach of just creating a new workspace and importing your project.